# how to use case with count function in oracle plsql

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

here is the query, i want to use case statement with count function in oracle.

```
  Select case when count(*) > 0 then 'doSomething' else 'doSomething'  
    from student where student_name='faizan ahmed' and student_father='ahmed' and UPPER(student_dob)=UPPER('01-FEB-19');
```

please help me out, using plsql code.

> ORA-00905: missing keyword
>   00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword"

Comment: You are missing an `END` at the end of your `CASE` expression.

Comment: `case when count(*) > 0 then 'doSomething' else 'doSomething' end`

Answer (score 2):

For this purpose, use `exists` instead:

```
Select (case when exists (select 1
                          from student
                          where student_name = 'faizan ahmed' and
                                student_father = 'ahmed' and
                                upper(student_dob) = upper('01-FEB-19');
             then 'doSomething'
             else 'doSomethingElse' 
       end)
from dual;
```

`EXISTS` is usually more efficient than a count, because it can stop at the first matching row instead of aggregating the whole table.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing an `END` for `CASE`:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT (*) > 0 THEN 
                 'doSomething' 
            ELSE 'doSomething' 
       END                                  --> This
  FROM student
 WHERE     student_name = 'faizan ahmed'
       AND student_father = 'ahmed'
       AND UPPER (student_dob) = date '2019-02-01' -- No! UPPER ('01-FEB-19');
```

It is easier to spot if you **format** code you write.

Apart from that, `STUDENT_DOB` seems to be a **date**. If so, then don't compare it to a string (because `'01-feb-19'` IS a string) but to a date (`date '2019-02-01'` - it is a *date literal*, consists of the `date` keyword and `yyyy-mm-dd` value).

Also, it is strange that you used `UPPER` with that "date" string, but all your names are lowercase. Hm?